# How do I setup a game room in pure actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Height, Width, Background Color, placing objects in the room and such. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might want to go into more detail about what you consider a "game room" - this could mean different things to different people

Comment: 2d. I just mean a room that I can define the size of and place objects in. For example, an 800x600 room with a black background, with 1 ball object in it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 6):

Read the manual. Seriously.

Answer (score 3):

```
// An 800x600 black room with a red ball, you say?..
//
// This is written & tested in Flash CS4.
// Hopefully you just need some sample code to explore,
// also I recommend geting familiar with the AS3 language reference:
//   http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

// Background: a black rectangle.
var background:Sprite = new Sprite();
with( background.graphics ) {
    beginFill( 0x000000, 1.0 );
    drawRect( 0, 0, 800, 600 );
    endFill();
}
addChild( background ); // add it to the stage

// Red ball.
var ball:Sprite = new Sprite();
with( ball.graphics ) {
    beginFill( 0xff0000, 1.0 );
    drawCircle( 0, 0, 100 );
    endFill();
}
addChild( ball );

// Start the ball in the center of the room
ball.x = 400;
ball.y = 300;

// When we click the ball, move it to a new location.
ball.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, moveBall );

function moveBall( e:MouseEvent ) :void {
    ball.x = Math.random() * 800;
    ball.y = Math.random() * 600;
}

// Hope this helps... Flash & Actionscript 3 is a very rich environment,
// there's a lot to learn & discover. I learn new tricks with each project.
```

Comment: You wrote the whole thing!! :-p Considering the OP's question, I don't know if this is helpful but you get points for writing the whole thing :-p

Comment: This took less than 5 minutes to crank out! I've written more AS3 than I care to admit, I can do it in my sleep now...

Answer (score 0):

Create a sprite. `var room:Sprite = new Sprite();`

Get the graphics object. `var g:Graphics = room.graphics;`

Draw:

```
g.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);

g.drawRect(0,0,800,600);

g.endFill();
```

Rinse and repeat. Children are added to "room" via `room.addChild(chair);`, but they're created the same way.

There are lots of tutorials out there for how to start up a simple project.

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withmxmlc/
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials.php

Answer (score 0):

If you use the free opensource IDE FlashDevelop, then you can just set the properties in the properties panel.

If you have a pure actionscript project you can use the SWF meta tag to define stage properties:

```
[SWF(width='800', height='600', backgroundColor='#000000', frameRate='30')]
```

Without more info, I can't really answer much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The first two articles of the [Flash Adventure Game Tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/11/22/create-your-own-flash-adventure-game.aspx), [Creating a level](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/56900.aspx) and [Loading a level](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/56911.aspx), show you how to create a 2D map with free TaT level editor and then display it in a Flash game. Later articles cover adding items to the level and then loading them into a game.

[image]